# What do I need to change with my jQuery to make .fadeIn work in Safari and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, safari

My body .fadeIn works in Chrome and Firefox, but I can't get it working in Safari or IE. I've tried moving the order the scripts are read (before external .css, after .css), I've checked that the script is linked correctly and to the correct file – nothing. Here is the html as I have it now:

```
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/developmentjquery-1.11.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").hide().fadeIn("slow");    
    });
    </script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/file.css"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Title of site</title>
</head>
```

The only .css on the body is:

```
    body {
background-color: #ffffff;
margin: 0px;
overflow-x:hidden;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to set the css of body as

```
body{
opacity:0;
}
```

and use jquery

```
$('body').animate({opacity:1});
```

And you can also set the time as the second argument of animate function if needed

Comment: Unless this is your only animation I would avoid animating opacity with jQuery.animate(). Animating opacity causes major performance issues. If animating the opacity works for you I would recommend using the velocity.js plugin as it majorly increases performance over the .animate() function.
http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Comment: I still haven't fixed the problem, but I removed the css stylesheet and ran the effect with just html – the fadeIn worked; but when I have the stylesheet linked, the <script> no longer runs the fadeIn.

You can see that the jQuery is working, because the page reloads (increased the fadeIn to 10sec …screen remained white for 10 seconds and then loaded the whole page), but there isn't the desired fadeIn.

Does this sound like a stylesheet problem?

Comment: then the root of the problem is definetly with css .... earlier @steely also had some issue like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262000/jquery-animation-duration-acting-like-a-delay/29262882#29262882) , the probem was a css element called transisition that was overiding the animate function

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing jQuery twice.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/developmentjquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
```

Take out the locally stored one leaving

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Referencing jQuery twice causes many effects issues.

Comment: I removed the local .js file reference – still no .fadeIn in Safari or EI …unfortunately.

I have other .js running on the page that works in all the browsers (smoothscroll and lightbox), so I'm at a bit of a loss – I might try your idea @CPR43, but I worry about the page not being visible at all if javascript is disabled.

Comment: I ultimately resolved this by changing the fadeIn, which I was trying to have occur on the $("body"), to instead occur on a <div id> wrapped around most of the elements within the <body>.