# jQuery animation duration acting like a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Here's my script:

```
greenGoButton.click(function() {
    $(".road-animate").css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "running");
    $(".buildings-animate").css("-webkit-animation-play-state", "running");
    road.addClass('road-animate');
    buildings.addClass('buildings-animate');

//THIS IS WHAT IS DELAYING

    redCar.animate({ left: 1000 }, 5000);
    greenCar.animate({ left: 1000 }, 5000);

//END of what I'm asking about :)

    infoScreen.toggleClass('screen-two screen-three');
    setTimeout(function() {screenTransition(2)} ,1500);
});
```

For some reason, the animation for REDCAR and GREENCAR is not starting until AFTER the 5 seconds, then it hurries across the screen in about half a second.

I've tried:

```
    redCar.stop().animate({ left: 1000 }, 5000);
    greenCar.stop().animate({ left: 1000 }, 5000);
```

and:

```
    redCar.animate({ left: travelDistance }, { duration: 5000, queue: false });
    greenCar.animate({ left: travelDistance }, { duration: 5000, queue: false });
```

and:

```
    redCar.stop().animate({ left: travelDistance }, { duration: 5000, queue: false });
    greenCar.stop().animate({ left: travelDistance }, { duration: 5000, queue: false });
```

Help me Obi-Wan Kenobi, you're my only hope. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my gosh, I hate when it's something stupid...

I had this in my css on the class I was animating:

```
transition: all 1.5s ease-in-out;
```

And it was overriding my jQuery animation... Remove it and it's fixed! :P

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you need.This is a very sloppy method .Avoid using it if you find some other method.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   redCar.stop().animate({ left:+200 }, 1000); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. Turns out it was in my css.. ⍨